# Ping a Bluetooth device from an Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, ping

I would like to know if a Bluetooth device given its MAC address is available (on and within reach) or not. Something like a ping, some quick method.

I tried to check by trying to establish a connection but it takes up to 12 seconds. Do you know any faster way?

Comment: You can check if it's broadcasting which might be quicker

Comment: @fdezjose Have you found a quicker way to ping a bluetooth device knowing the MAC Address? If you try to connect you can get something like: "Host down", "connections refused" "Timeout"...
But it takes around 5 seconds... not very quick

Comment: @fjbelchi I installed CyanogenMod on the phone and then since I had root access I used BlueZ commands. hcitool name <bdaddr> proved to be the fastest way. (It was for a research project so I could do all the rooting stuff, not a good idea to do it this way if you plan to release the app to the market).

Answer (score 0):

If the device you are looking for is discoverable then doing a device discovery is probably the most efficient.

Comment: Device discovery usually takes no less than 10 seconds for new devices.

Comment: You can stop the discovery process as soon as your device is found. If the device is nearby it should show up in 2-3 seconds or less in typical use cases