# How to ping BluetoothDevice by using API?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm looking for a way to ping a remote `BluetoothDevice` I only know the MAC-address of. I want to know (at least one time per second or faster) whether the device is still in range of my Android phone or not. I don't have access to the other devices (so I could not create a client-software). It would be great if I don't have to root the phone and I could use standard API for it. But if there is no other possibility, I could imagine to root it.

I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281231/ping-a-bluetooth-device-from-an-android-device), but it does not really solve my problem.

I've already tried some ways:

1. do periodic DeviceDiscovery
2. using `hcitool -i hci0 inq --flush` in combination with `hcidump`
3. using `l2ping`

I even tried to extract the important lines from `BlueZ` stack and implement them native with JNI to my code.

My problems with these ideas:

1. too slow (each device is only found one time each 9-13 seconds)
2. too slow (on a linux pc it is a lot of faster. on an android-phone it is as slow as 1.)
3. it is a little faster than `hcitool` but on the most devices it requires a pairing

My next idea would be the following:

I want to create an insecure socket to a remote device and perform a `ServiceDiscovery` on it as kind of a ping. As far as I understand `l2ping` does nearly the same (only with name-resolving where is no API function available for). But I don't really know how to perform a `ServiceDiscovery`. I nearly read the whole Bluetooth-API from Android and tried something like `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID myUUID)` with different UUIDs but I don't really know what I'm doing there.

So I have two questions:

1. How to perform a remote `ServiceDiscovery` on `BluetoothDevices` programmatically?
2. Are there other ways/ideas, how to periodically ping a bluetooth-devices?

**edit:**

```
    mMyDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MY_MAC);
    mMyUUID = UUID.fromString("00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    try {
        mBT_Socket = mMyDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mMyUUID);
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        mBT_Socket.connect();
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Idea I would like to share in terms pinging the nearby device will be to send a bluetooth request to nearby device using
OBEX Push UUID. I am not sure how long will it take but its worth a try.  In this method you create a connection with RFComm Socket to the OBEX Server on the other device. Note every device has a 
native OBEX Server running which can receive an OBEX Push request.
OBEX Push UUID is "00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB".

In this manner your client side device will not be able to connect to the nearby device if the nearby bluetooth device is not available and you might get
a disconnection wihtin 1-2 seconds.

Time frames on two things you can note here 
1. How much time does it take to get a connection, if the nearby device is available?
2. How much time will it take to know if you are not able to make a connection. If the bluetooth device is not available?

Comment: thanks for your idea, I already tried this (by fluke) when I was playing around with `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID myUUID)`. I tried this UUID and it resulted immediatly in a popup-dialog: "device 123 would like to pair". I dont want to pair the devices. I only want to ping it. The client must not know that it was pinged.

Comment: So if you somehow depress this dialog box then you will solve your problem?

Comment: Can you share the code where you attempt to make a connection using RFComm?

Comment: if i can depress this dialog, i can use l2ping, that would work

Comment: i edited my question and added the code where i try to establish a rfcomm-socket. there is no exception or anything. that works. but it creates a "pairing dialog" on the client side

Comment: ok Try using a different in createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord UUID a wrong one and see what exception you get when the client bluetooth device is active? If you get an exception explaining that Service Not supported then it means the device is alive. And then try to run the same code when bluetooth device is switched off now at this point do you get a different exception?

Comment: Also does this method "createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord" invokes successfully if the other device is around? I am assuming the other device gets a pairing request when you call the mBT_Socket.connect(); method so if you can determine whether the device is alive before executing this method then you are done

Comment: Tom, if you want to do only service discovery, use "sdptool browse", looks like you have access to the bluez native lib, with above command you can search for the services (SDP record) in all available nearby devices

Comment: @TomMekken Did you resolved your issue? Please can you update us all if it did, I am interested in knowing. Many Thanks

Comment: no i haven't. sorry. i was busy the other days and couldn't continue in this project. So I tried to take a fake-UUID, but there is no exception. I only receive the cached Services of the other phone (no matter whether the bluetooth is on or off). The essential LogCat-Output is:

- BluetoothService.cpp: stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
- BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
- BluetoothEventLoop.cpp: onDiscoverServicesResult: D-Bus error: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed (Host is down)

Comment: @TomMekken did you try to find out where you actually got the Pairing request dialogue on the other phone? Does it appear on executing "createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID myUUID)" or "mBT_Socket.connect();"

Comment: I checked it out: mBT_Socket.connect() causes the "Pairing-Request"

Comment: @TomMekken and do you get any exception on createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID myUUID) if the other bluetooth device is not around?

Comment: nope, but that would be great ;-)
this would be exactly what I need. Socket.connect() throws such an Exception (after 5sec). But this causes a Parinigrequest. Only initiating the Socket doesn't do anything.